# Using property parameter in Camel annotation

Tags: java, apache-camel

I found this approach from Camel's website which shows how to use @Produce annotation to create an pseudo-method call for sending message to JMS queue:

```
public interface MyListener {
    String sayHello(String name);
}

public class MyBean {
    @Produce(uri = "activemq:foo")
    protected MyListener producer;

    public void doSomething() {
        // lets send a message
        String response = producer.sayHello("James");
    }
}
```

However, in my scenario, I need the ability to set different JMS queue for different environment. Therefore the JMS queue in:

```
    @Produce(uri = "activemq:foo")
```

needs to come from a property file rather than hardcoded.

How can I achieve this? Is there any other ways I can use to achieve without using annotation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation about using property placeholders

- http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

When you setup this, then you can use placeholders in the uri string you define with the annotation

```
@Produce(uri = "activemq:{{myQueue}}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ProducerTemplate described here:
http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html

```
@Bean
public class MyBean {

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate template

    public void doSomething() {
        // lets send a message
        template.sendBody("your_mq_address", "James");
    }
}
```

Remember to define the template in the camel context:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camelContext">
    <contextScan/>
    <template id="template"/>
</camelContext>
```